# Why does my Gravatar periodically vanish from stack overflow et al?

Tags: support, gravatar, caching

For the third time since I started using stack overflow, my gravatar appears to have stopped working. Right now I'm just seeing the funky IP address based image:

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c1ce7f378bd3de35cc5fb74ea0d23992?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

..when I go to my gravatar settings it says the link should be:

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/418a18dde0d9cb4cc434bd38a329190c.png

So what's happened? Is it just some weird caching thing here at work? I'm fairly sure I didn't change anything..

Comment: Browser cache problem? That usually solves it.

Comment: That avatar totally looks like a swastika.

Comment: It is a swastika. Nazi! (although I can't really see avatars from work, I trust random, so I'll take his word for it)

Comment: Weird.. it seems to be working again now. For the record thuogh, the black and white swastica-like image was generated by Gravatar!

Answer (score 1):

To provide closure to those who may be currently experiencing this intermittent issue (see [Broken gravatars in chat and on main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159166/broken-gravatars-in-chat-and-on-main-site)), broken Gravatar avatars are many times the result of server issues on Gravatar's end.

Gravatar [serves approximately ~20 billion images per day](http://5by5.tv/bigwebshow/29) across their user's accounts. If each avatar file size is [5 KB](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c1ce7f378bd3de35cc5fb74ea0d23992?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG), Gravatar expends to the upwards of 95 TB of data transfer daily, not accounting for new avatar uploads or other server operations. Bottom line - issues are bound to occur. Luckily, their server engineers  are typically quick to resolve these issues.

Should you be currently experiencing an issue with Gravatar-generated avatars on Stack Overflow, your best option is to contact them via their [support website](https://en.gravatar.com/site/contact-us/). Otherwise, just wait it out until it's been resolved.