# Broken gravatars in chat and on main site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, gravatar

[image]

It's not just Ask Ubuntu, I've seen it here on MSO too. whats up? Did the hats break things?

Comment: GAH! I was just about to post this so that people wouldn't freak out. :-

Comment: The other is older. Only Jon Skeet can post a dupe and have the original closed.

Comment: Hah! Talk about timing...

Comment: @Luke it's older by 13 seconds. It *really* doesn't matter. ;) #AntiJokeChicken

Comment: gravatar *hates* hats

Comment: @AnnaLear except I got a downvote for my dup, even though it was first! Time to cry in my waffles!

Comment: @bluefeet I can delete it and make it all better? :)

Comment: Why's everyone giving me blank stares? *http://instantrimshot.com/*

Comment: @Luke not bad for for a man with such an ugly face. ;)

Comment: @anna since it is a dup feel free.

Comment: e-mail from gravatar.com "We indeed experienced issues with Gravatar yesterday. The problem should now be solved."

Answer (score 14):

Gravatar is experiencing problems - they're returning a `504 Gateway Timeout` error for all requests. It has nothing to do with Stack Exchange. You'll just have to deal with it for a while, until they fix whatever their issue is. Any Gravatars still in your cache will continue to show until your browser attempts to update them again.

Comment: Look ma! I'm getting cool hats!

Comment: Why do you got people's avatars in your cache? You got a sexual thing going on with them er sumthin?